# A valid application name for Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I have authentication in Firebase for my application

Whether in the Firebase **Package Name** is the name taken from:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myName.myName">
```

or

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myName"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.0.4"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

In my case, these names are different

Answer (score 0):

You should use the application ID as provided by your gradle build.  It cannot change after you've published your app to Play.  It must be unique among all Android apps published to the Play store, and is how Firebase will identify your app.

The package name in the manifest doesn't have anything to do with this ID (it used to a long time ago, but not any more).  While they might be the same for newly created projects, the package name can change between versions of your app published to Play.  You can think of it more as a namespace for resources provided by the module where the manifest lives.

The [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module) might also be helpful to read.